# Leftidx problem: upper indices have different height

Tags: spacing, subscripts, superscripts

When using the `leftidx` package to create the same upper index on both sides of `\Bbbk[G]`, the indices have different height and look ugly. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{leftidx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[ \leftidx{^D}{\Bbbk[G]}{^D} \]
\end{document}
```

I tried wrapping `\Bbbk[G]` in `\left.` and `\right.`, which solves the height problem, but it creates undesired spacing on the left. I am opting against negative hspace, hoping that someone knows a good solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{leftidx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[ \leftidx{^D}{\Bbbk[G]}{^D} \]
\[ \leftidx{^D}{{\Bbbk[G]}}{^D} \]
\end{document}
```

The extra `{}` mean that the base is a single atom that gets measured for the left and right superscript, otherwise the left script goes on the `k` and the right script goes on the `]`

Comment: @egreg, David Carlisle: You both are my heroes. I flipped a coin and accepted the second answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add a pair of braces, so that TeX will see the subformula as a unit, without adding extra space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{leftidx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[ \leftidx{^D}{{\Bbbk[G]}}{^D} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]